# AWS Organisation 'Service Access Policy' Deny ability to delete S3 bucket EXCEPT for user identified in 'Condition' using aws:username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies, aws-organizations, aws-scp

I am trying to use AWS Service Control Policy **(SCP)** on an Organization account and prevent users from the management account from deleting any S3 bucket except for a specific IAM User who is allowed to delete the S3 bucket.

I have implemented this policy below and specified the 'Condition' to only allow specific IAM user (via aws:username) from deleting the S3 bucket.
However, I am finding that this 'Condition' is not working as expected as if the user 'BobSmith' tries to delete an S3 bucket via the AWS S3 dashboard, he gets a 'Permission Denied' message

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Statement1",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteBucket"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotEqualsIfExists": {
          "aws:username": [
            "BobSmith"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The user 'BobSmith' logs into the Management Account and then uses 'Switch Role' to login to the Organization Unit (OU) account and then tries to delete a bucket from S3.

My understanding is that the above policy 'should' Deny anyone the ability to delete any S3 bucket **EXCEPT** for IAM User BobSmith but so far, BobSmith is not able to delete any S3 bucket.

Have I not understood the above policy correctly? am I missing something or doing something incorrectly?
I would appreciate any pointers. Thanks.

Comment: That SCP adds an explicit deny but it doesn't itself grant BobSmith permission to delete buckets.  You need to explicitly *allow* the action in BobSmith's user policy.

Comment: @erik258 but wouldn't the 'Condition' excludes BobSmith from the Deny? i.e. it will Deny everyone, except for BobSmith?

Comment: Yes, but IAM is a Deny by Default ("Positive Security Model").  You've set an SCP so that no other users can be effectively allowed to DeleteBucket regardless of explicit allows .  But BobSmith must also have an explicit allow or the action will be denied by default.